# compress soap messages between service layer and client code

Tags: web-services, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, soap

I refered this link :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53718/Extending-WCF-Part-II
    i have to compress request and response messages coming from the WCF web service i have used the above way having error on proxy creation and calling method...
    error as fallow:
    "Content Type application/x-gzip was not supported by service `http://lo/DeskWCF/Demo.svc.` The client and service bindings may be mismatched."
    please thanks in advance.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting IIS gzip compression to work with Silverlight WCF service on .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201982/getting-iis-gzip-compression-to-work-with-silverlight-wcf-service-on-net-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at these questions, and you should be able to get it working

[Getting IIS gzip compression to work with Silverlight WCF service on .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201982/getting-iis-gzip-compression-to-work-with-silverlight-wcf-service-on-net-4-0)

[How to get gzip compression working in WCF 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680087/how-to-get-gzip-compression-working-in-wcf-4-5)